# finish the Dialog and Activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, activity-finish

I have a activity which start with a alertdialog

when i press back button only dialog get close.

I want to close both dialog and activity.

How to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the `OnCancelListener` that can be set for the [Dialog.setOnCancelListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29)

There you can call `finish()` which will finish your `Activity`, too.

Comment: It should be called, if you press the back button while the dialog is open, thats what you want, right?

Answer (score 4):

This code works like a charm!!

```
public void showAlertDialog(final Activity activity, String title, String message, Boolean status) {

  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
        alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                activity.finish();
            }
        });

  alertDialog.show();
}
```

I had determine to always receive the activity, because I always send ActivityName.this, instead of sending just the context. But then I received the context. But here, I can not cancel the activity with just the context, I need the activity. So, always send the activity, in order to be able to manipulate it from outside the same activity.